# How to compress a set of unique natural numbers and compare two such sets?

Tags: php, algorithm, search, binary, compression

Web application compares pairs of sets of positive integers. Each set has only unique values, no greater than 210 000 000 (fits into 28 bits). Up to 5 000 000 values in each set.

Comparing sets A & B, need three result sets: "unique to A", "unique to B", "common to A & B". Particular task is to answer a question "is number N present in set S?"

So far the project runs in limited resources of a shared hosting, under LAMP stack. Quick'n'dirty solution I came up with was to outsource the job to hosting's MySQL, which has more resources. Temporary table for each set, the only column with the numbers is the primary index. Rarely sets are small enough to fit into engine=Memory, which is fast. It works, but too slow.

Looking for a way to keep a set like this in-memory, effective for the task of searching a particular number within. Keeping memory footprint as low as possible.

I came up to an idea of coding each set as a bit mask of 2^28 bits (32 Mb). A number present in the set = 1 bit set. 5 mln numbers = 5 mln bits set out of 210mln. Many zeroes == can compress effectively?

Seems like I'm inventing a bicycle. Please direct me to a "well-known" solution to this particular case of binary compression. I read about Huffman coding, which seems not the right solution, as its focus is size reduction, while my task requires many searches over a compressed set.

**Upd.** Just found an article on [Golomb coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding#Use_for_run-length_encoding) and an example of its [application to run-length encooding](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~ayoussef/cs225/lossless.html#golomb).

Comment: 210,000,000 requires 28 bits; 2^23 is a bit more than eight million.

Comment: @rici: You're right, fixed. 23 was from an optimization I was considering atm : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard compression technique available for represented large sets of integers in a range, which allows for efficient iteration (so it can easily do intersection, union, set difference, etc.) but does not allow random access (so it's no good for "is N in S"). For this particular problem, it will reduce the dataset to around seven bits each, which would be around 8MB for sets of size 5,000,000. In case it's useful, I'll describe it below.

Bit-vectors of size 210,000,000 bits (26MB each, roughly) are computationally efficient, both to answer the "is N in S" query, and for bitwise operations, since you can do them rapidly with vectorized instructions on modern processors; it's probably as fast as you're going to get for a 5,000,000-element intersection computation. It consumes a lot of memory, but if you've got that much memory, go for it.

The compression technique, which is simple and just about optimal if the sets are uniformly distributed random samples of the specified size, is as follows:

1. Sort the set (or ensure that it is sorted).
2. Set the "current value" to 0.
3. For each element in the set, in order:

   a. subtract the "current value" from the element;

   b. while that difference is at least 32, output a single `1` bit and subtract 32 from the difference;

   c. output a single `0` bit, followed by the difference encoded in five bits.

   d. set the "current value" to one more than the element

To justify my claim that the compression will result in around seven bits per element:

It's clear that every element will occupy six bits (`0` plus a five-bit delta); in addition, we have to account for the `1` bits in step 3b. Note, however, that the sum of all the deltas is exactly the largest element in the set, which cannot be more than 210,000,000 and consequently, we cannot execute step 3b more than 210,000,000/32 times. So step 3b. will account for less than seven million bits, while step 3c will account for 6 * 5,000,000 bits, for a total of 37 million, or 7.4 bits per element (in practice, it will usually be a bit less than this).

Comment: Memory is quite limited, that's why I am reinventing the wheel. Have just found [Golomb coding for run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding#Use_for_run-length_encoding) - would you expect it to be a more effective in the particular case, where there's much more 0's than 1's?